# Class Design related clarification c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a design related question. So please guide me on how to do this?

Right now, I have a xml structure which will be in this format.

```
<Sheet id="abc"/>
     <Elements>
        <Element id="xyz">
           <value>23</value>
        </Element>
        <Element id="sdz">
           <value>46</value>
        </Element>
        ...
    </Elements>
</Sheet>
```

So, we have a class like this to store each & every element of the sheet.

```
Sheet
{
    Public string SheetId
    {
      get; set;
    }

    //all Elements will be stored in the below collection   
    Public IList<IDictionary<string, string>> Elements
    {
      get; set;
    }
}
```

But now for few sheets the format has been changed to the below structure.

```
<abc> //SheetId
    <Elements>
       <Record>
            <Element1/>
            <Element2/>
            <Element3/>
            <Element4/>
       </Record>      
       <Record>
            <Element1/>
            <Element2/>
            <Element3/>
            <Element4/>
       </Record>
       ...   
</abc>
```

So, we need to create a Generic class to hold the above xml formats and we don't want to have different object to store these.

I mean in future if we have some other xml format also we need to accommodate the same without any change in the Sheet class.

So, can you please advise me on how to design the Sheet Class.?

Ok. let me explain how my app works.

Actually we have around 200 sheets(in other words measures).

1) User will upload the sheet data in xml format (all sheets in xml file) & edit the same if they want Or Enter the data in the screen (dynamic screen generated using the xml template) if they dont want to upload.

2) Then the data will be stored in the Sheet object and it will go through lot of Validation process and finally the data will be converted to xml again and stored in the db.

You can ask why you want to store this as XML? The reason is we dont want to create 200 aspx pages for this same kind of data and thats why we are generating the sheet pages dynamically using the xml templates. Also, we will be adding, updating or deleting sheets frequently.

Ok. I think now you will have some idea about this issue.

To be more clear, all the elements in my XML file will be displayed as a field in the aspx page. It maybe a Textbox, dropdown & etc....

Comment: And there are on `Id`s or `<Value>`s in the 2nd example?

Comment: Yes. The Sheet Id is now the root element in the 2nd example. "abc".

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Also, I forgot to tell you one thing, in the 2nd example the <Value> will be <Element4>.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend designing your class based on what the information actually represents and how your software plans to utilize the data, not the XML format being used.

You should always be able to do the transposition from the data format into the structure which best represents how your program will use this data.

Comment: Hi Reed, Thanks for your reply. But the problem here is, the customers will be uploading only xml files and we need to parse the same and do lot of analysis on the xml data. Also, we are storing the entire xml in SQL DB.

Comment: @GSP: Then I would suggest basing your class design off the information you plan to store in the DB.  You can map the XML -> your structure, analyze it, then store as needed.

Comment: Hi Reed, I am not clear on what you are saying? Also, one thing I want to tell you, this web app is being used for the past 10 years and I don't think our managers are ready to embrace any major design change.

Comment: Reed is stating that you must design your data constructs based on your business entities not on the fact that the data is stored in a sheet. If your sheet holds a bunch of data on Cars you need to focus on the Cars entity not so much that they are contained in the sheet. you wouldn't write a table class and a row class and a cell class just becuase your data was stored n a database.

Comment: If you get the class structure right you can easily serialize and deserialize the classes to and from xml quite easily.

Comment: @gsirianni: I dont think you have understood my requirement properly. Please see my question and I have added some more explanation.